# Eigenvalues of Hermitian matrix, reflexion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If given me Hermitian matrix, with eigenvalues $1, -1$. Is it necessarily a reflection matrix?

The matrix:

$$\frac15\begin{pmatrix}-3 & 4i\\-4i & 3\end{pmatrix}$$

It is possible to say that if hermitian matrix with eigenvalues 1, -1, then it is the matrix of reflection? 
Thank you

Comment: the eigenvalues of this matrix are $5$ and $-5$

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question. Was a mistake. @john

Comment: this doesn't change the eigenvalues!

Comment: Eigenvalues are not 1, -1?

Comment: It is possible to say that if hermitian matrix with eigenvalues 1, -1, then it is the matrix of reflection?

Comment: How do you define a reflection matrix?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrix with eigenvalues $\pm 1$, then a unit eigenvector $e_1$ with eigenvalue $1$ must be orthogonal to a unit eigenvector $e_2$ with eigenvalue $-1$. And,
$$
                 A( \alpha_1 e_1 + \alpha_2 e_2) = \alpha_1 e_1 -\alpha_2 e_2.
$$
That looks like a reflection.